# Como incluir labels no matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

AP_X = [10,20,30,40]
AP_Y = [50,60,70,80]
plt.scatter(AP_X, AP_Y, color="green")
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.xlim(0, 100)

plt.show()
```

Ele exibe um gráfico com as posições x,y dos meus 4 pontos.

Como faço para incluir, em cada ponto, um *label* indicando 1, 2, 3 e 4?

Comment: Veja se o método [`matplotlib.pyplot.text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) é o que precisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe funcionalidade pronta para isto ao gerar o gráfico. É preciso utilizar o **annotate( )** para marcar cada ponto, ou qualquer texto, que se deseja. Como você sabe quais são os pontos, basta iterar sobre os valores e imprimí-los no gráfico:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

AP_X = [10,20,30,40]
AP_Y = [50,60,70,80]
plt.scatter(AP_X, AP_Y, color="green")
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.xlim(0, 100)

### IMPRIMIDO AS COORDENADAS ###
for i in range(len(AP_X)):
    label = '(' + str(AP_X[i]) + ', ' + str(AP_Y[i]) + ')'
    plt.annotate(label, xy=(AP_X[i], AP_Y[i]), xytext=(AP_X[i]+2, AP_Y[i]+2))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!